# Kafka Stream multiple punctuator execution per iteration

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a transformer with a schedule

```
    context.schedule(scanFrequency, PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, new MyPunctuator(stateStore));
```

Then my Punctuator class

```
public class MyPunctuator implements Punctuator {

    @Override
    public void punctuate(final long timestamp) {
    }
}
```

Now the weird thing id, that when the schedule works is invoking the punctuator per iteration 4 times

```
[StreamThread-1] INFO MyPunctuator  - [Punctuator Scan] - Timestamp 1660083164829
[StreamThread-1] INFO MyPunctuator  - store=0
[StreamThread-1] INFO MyPunctuator  - [Punctuator Scan] - Timestamp 1660083164830
[StreamThread-1] INFO MyPunctuator  - store=1
[StreamThread-1] INFO MyPunctuator  - [Punctuator Scan] - Timestamp 1660083164831
[StreamThread-1] INFO MyPunctuator  - store=0
[StreamThread-1] INFO MyPunctuator  - [Punctuator Scan] - Timestamp 1660083164832
[StreamThread-1] INFO MyPunctuator  - store=0
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the punctuation type, this is how the Schedule - Punctuate works. You can compare this example with your usecase.

### PunctuationType.STREAM_TIME

If you schedule a Punctuator function every 10 seconds based on PunctuationType.STREAM_TIME and if you process a stream of 60 records with consecutive timestamps from 1 (first record) to 60 seconds (last record), then punctuate() would be called 6 times. This happens regardless of the time required to actually process those records. punctuate() would be called 6 times regardless of whether processing these 60 records takes a second, a minute, or an hour.

### PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME

When wall-clock-time (i.e. PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME) is used, punctuate() is triggered purely by the wall-clock time. Reusing the example above, if the Punctuator function is scheduled based on PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, and if these 60 records were processed within 20 seconds, punctuate() is called 2 times (one time every 10 seconds). If these 60 records were processed within 5 seconds, then no punctuate() is called at all. Note that you can schedule multiple Punctuator callbacks with different PunctuationType types within the same processor by calling ProcessorContext#schedule() multiple times inside init() method.

Comment: yeah I read the documentation, but it does not explain the behavior that I'm explaining here

Comment: The example given in the docs is misleading, When wall-clock-time (i.e. PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME) is used, punctuate() is called continuously at regular intervals defined irrespective of the data records sent.

Answer (score 0):

Transformer is initialized some random number of times.  I have 4 threads, one topic, 2 partitions and I get 10 punctuators.  I don't understand it.